# On the Phone in the States

Tags: word, visual, rebus, english

[image: rebus]

The answer is a relevant word or set of words.

Comment: Since this was intended to be solvable with basic knowledge, I will note to the non-programmers that ! can mean Not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer here is:

> '**#**' - otherwise known as a **POUND SIGN** on telephone keypads in the United States (hence the title - although more on that later...).

To find this, we need to read the diagram as follows:

> *Line 1:*
>  **PAS** (SAP, backwards)
>  **INPUT** ('a' here is the *input* for the function)
>  **OASI** ('OASIS' missing its final letter)
>
>  *Line 2:*
>  **NO** (element 102 in the Periodic Table is Nobelium, whose symbol is 'No')
>  **SCAR** (the villain from *The Lion King*)
>  **UAS** ('USA' with the second and third letters switched)
>  **I** (the square root of -1, censored here in the image, is known in mathematics as *i*)
>  **NUMBER** (a [synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign) of the final answer to the whole puzzle, which is what is pictured here)
>
>  *Line 3:*
>  **NA** (North America)
>  **SINNER** (i.e. 'not a saint')
>  **ODAS** (the letters of SODA rearranged as per the number ordering 2341)
>  **INDEX** (index finger)
>
>  *Line 4:*
>  **TERS** (letters 1, 2, 3 and 8 of TERmiteS)
>  **A'S IN SQUARE** (say what you see!)
>  **IA** (abbreviation for Iowa)
>  **SI** ('Yes' in Spanish)
>
>  *Line 5:*
>  **NICE** (Santa's 'nice' list)
>  **GA** (abbreviation for Georgia)
>  **SING** (say what you see!)
>  **RAM** (ditto)
>
>  *Line 6:*
>  **NAS** (several North Americas)
>  **INN** (the inn in Bethlehem, approached by Mary and Joseph)
>  **ANCY** (CYAN - the colour shown here - with its halves exchanged)

Finally:

> string all of these letters together and respace appropriately to find the following text:
>
>  'P' as in 'PUT'
>  'O' as in 'OSCAR'
>  'U' as in 'UMBER'
>  'N' as in 'NERO'
>  'D' as in 'DEXTER'
>  'S' as in 'SQUARE'
>  'I' as in 'ICE'
>  'G' as in 'GRAM'
>  'N' as in 'NANCY'

What have we got here?

> This is one side of a conversation someone might have **on the phone** in order to spell out the words '**POUND SIGN**' - thereby providing a *double*-meaning to the title of this puzzle!

Comment: Great job! Although noting the clue for rot13('ahzore' vf npghnyyl n fvatyr punenpgre (thrff jung))

Comment: @Amoz That was the one image I wasn't sure about... I reasoned that it probably had the same number of letters as the clue two after it since its blank space was of the same length. I still don't really get what it should be (or why), tbh...

Comment: That picture looks familiar, where have you seen it before?

Comment: @Amoz Ha, I do know what it *is*, just not how to describe it in a word beginning with what I need it to begin with :)

Comment: Ah but you already did. "The answer here is '?'".Might be a US synonym.